# ipcRenderer not receiving message from main process

Tags: electron

I can see the "Hello from renderer" alert, but not the "Goodbye from renderer" alert.

Running in Windows 10.

And I can't see the "received!" alert, which I should see it the ipcRenderer.on(...) worked.

## index.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow} = require("electron");

app.on('ready', () => {
  let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(
  {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
  mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    mainWindow.webContents.send("from-main", "teste");
  });
});
```

## index.html

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>test</title>

  <script src="./renderer.js"> </script>

  </head>

  <body>
      Wait...
  </body>

</html>
```

## renderer.js

```
alert('hello from renderer');
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.on('from-main', () => { alert('received!');} );
alert('goodbye from renderer');
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(
  {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences:{
      nodeIntegration:true
    }
  });
```

Please add nodeIntegration when you are creating the browser window.
You are using the Node API at your renderer. When you don't enable nodeIntegration then you won't be able to use any node modules at your renderer js.

To confirm this you can see this error message from your app debug console.

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    // open dev tools
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
    mainWindow.webContents.send("from-main", "teste");
  });
```

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

This means you didn't enable the nodeIntegration when you are creating the browserWindow.