# Child process spawn is producing TypeError "stdout.on is not a function" in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, child-process

Like the title says, I'm getting an error when trying to create an event handler for spawn.stdin.on `Uncaught TypeError: spn.stdout.on is not a function`. I'm using contextBridge as shown below and whenever I create a new spawn object it get's executed, but it throws an error when I create event handlers.

preload.js

```js
const {contextBridge, remote} = require('electron');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
  'api', {
    spawn: (cmd, args) => {
      return spawn(cmd, args);
    }
  }
);
```

And the function that's throwing the error.

```js
let spn = undefined;
let running = false;
let finishQueueItem = false;
function startQueue() {
  // if the queue is already running, then return
  if (running) return;

  if (!$q.length > 0) {
    let x = addToQueue(getConfig());
    if (!x) return;
  }

  running = true;
  let $i = $q.pop();
  let cmd = $p.DAINPath + "\\DAINAPP.exe";
  let args = parseConfig($i);

  spn = api.spawn(cmd, args);
  spn.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });

  spn.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    console.error(data.toString());
  });

  spn.on("exit", (code) => {
    console.log("Child process exited with code " + code.toString());
    spn = undefined;
    running = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Your electron version is? And can you share the main.js?

Comment: Electron version is 8.0.1. And most of the JavaScript is inside the main_window.html file.https://github.com/Gigaboy-01/DAIN-Plus

Answer (score 1):

```
let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(
  {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences:{
      nodeIntegration:true
    }
  });
```

Please add nodeIntegration when you are creating the browser window. You are using the Node API at your renderer. When you don't enable `nodeIntegration`, you won't be able to use any node modules at your renderer.

Similar case as this
[ipcRenderer not receiving message from main process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60227586/ipcrenderer-not-receiving-message-from-main-process/60227981#60227981)